# JS onclick Event Handler - Not Responding

Tags: javascript, image, events, onclick, mouseevent

What I'm trying to achieve: clicking on any image should either reveal a clear image if image is blurred or blur the image if image is clear

What's happening: clicking on blurred image clears the image, but clicking on it again does nothing. so, clicking on a clear image does not blur it (as it should).

Here's my code:

```
<script>

    window.onload = init;

    function init(e) {
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); 
        //var img = document.getElementById('pics');

        img[0].onclick = unblur;  // <- why not just img.onclick = unblur ??
        img[1].onclick = unblur;
        img[2].onclick = unblur;

        console.log(img);
/*
        var imageId = e.target.id;  //zero
        var img = document.getElementById(imageId);
        */

        //img.onclick = unblur;
    }

    function unblur(e) {

        var imageId = e.target.id;  //zero
        var img = document.getElementById(imageId);

        var imageSource = img.src; //zeroblur.jpg

        var clearImg = imageSource.substring(0, imageSource.length - 8);

        var unblurredImg = imageId.concat('.jpg');   // zero.jpg
        var blurredImg = imageId.concat('blur.jpg'); // zeroblur.jpg

        console.log(imageSource);
        console.log(img.src);
        //console.log(imageSource);


        if (img.src == unblurredImg) {  
            img.src = blurredImg;
        } else {
            img.src = unblurredImg;  // image is clear, so hide the pic
        }   

/*
         if (img.src == blurredImg) {
                img.src = unblurredImg;
        }
    } */
    //}
    } 

    /*  
        //if (!(imageId instanceof img)) {
        if (imageId !== "pics") {
            if (img.src == blurredImg) {  
                img.src = unblurredImg; 
             } else if (img.src == unblurredImg) {
                img.src = blurredImg;
             }   // image is blurred, so reveal the pic
        else {
            console.log("hi");
        }

        //debugger;
    }
}
*/
        /*
        var img = document.getElementById('zero');
        img.src = "zero.jpg";
        */



</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="pics">
<img id="zero" src="zeroblur.jpg">
<img id="one" src="oneblur.jpg">
<img id="two" src="two.jpg">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I also noticed that if I switch the conditions in the function, unblur(e), to the following...

```
if (img.src == unblurredImg) {  
    img.src = blurredImg;
} else {
    img.src = unblurredImg;  
}
```

there's no response at all if a user clicks on a blurred image, whereas before (code above) the blurred image will at least reveal the cleared image.

Why is this happening? I see no difference between the two, besides just switching the order of the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various mistakes in your example. Take a look at the Code Snippet for a working example of what you are trying to achieve.

As for your comment:

> // <- why not just img.onclick = unblur ??

Because `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements. Therefore, you must iterate through the elements to apply the `onclick` handlers to each one.

```js
(function(document) {
  var array = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].onclick = toggleBlur;
  }

  function toggleBlur(event) {
    var img = event.target;
    var oldSrc = img.src; // Save to display in the console
    if (img.src.endsWith("blur.jpg")) {
      img.src = img.id + ".jpg";
    } else {
      img.src = img.id + "blur.jpg"
    }
    console.log(oldSrc + " -> " + img.src + " on element.id=" + img.id);
  }
})(document);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="pics">
    <img id="zero" src="zero.jpg">
    <img id="one" src="one.jpg">
    <img id="two" src="twoblur.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Heather, your code works perfectly. But I still don't understand what was wrong with this part of my code:

        if (img.src == unblurredImg) {  
            img.src = blurredImg;
        } else {
            img.src = unblurredImg;  
        }

Could you please explain?

Comment: @Selena Likely because of the actual path of your images. For example, when I run your code in JSFiddle, `console.log(img.src)` returns `https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/file.jpg`, and you are trying to compare that whole string to `file.jpg`. Same with when I run it on Stack Overflow as a Code Snippet. Therefore your `if (img.src == unblurredImg`) is always `false` so your `else`-block always runs. Please accept the answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: You are correct, it was a mismatch in the file names. Thanks for the help!